# Eclipse: Perl EPIC debug & release mode execution mismatch

Tags: eclipse, perl, epic

I am noticing an execution mismatch of Perl in Eclipse EPIC plugin.

***Specifications:***

**Perl version:** (v5.12.4) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread

**Eclipse version:** Indigo Service Release 2

**EPIC version:** 0.6.53

***Consider the files & source codes below: (all source files are in same directory)***

**sample.pl**

```
use package1;

require "package1.pm";
require "package2.pm";

sampleFunction();

require "packagetest.pm";

packagetest::callSampleFunction();
```

**package1.pm**

```
package package1;

use Exporter;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);

our @EXPORT = qw(
    sampleFunction
);

sub sampleFunction {
    print "from package1.pm \n";    
}
```

**package2.pm**

```
package package1;  # declare the same package 'package1'

use Exporter;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);

our @EXPORT = qw(
    sampleFunction
);

sub sampleFunction {
    print "from package2.pm \n";    
}
```

**packagetest.pm**

```
package packagetest;

use package1;

sub callSampleFunction {
    sampleFunction();
}

1;
```

When I execute the sample.pl file in Eclipse EPIC, I am getting two different console outputs.

**Debug mode output:**

```
from package2.pm 
from package2.pm
```

**Run mode output:**

```
Subroutine sampleFunction redefined at D:/My.Soft.Dev/Perl_XS/package2.pm line 11.
from package1.pm 
from package2.pm
```

I have the below questions:

1) Why am I getting two different outputs here? Is it not a bug?

2) Which of the outputs shown is a "valid output"?

3) Can someone explain why is the particular output valid?

I tried to derive the reasons from my Perl knowledge. But I couldn't. So, I understood, I have to get to know more about Perl:))

**UPDATE:** I have created a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/e-p-i-c/bugs/669/

Looks like (1) is a bug in Perl debugger of 5.12.4 version

Comment: It would be interesting to see what other Perl versions/implementations do with this same setup.  Have you tried any other executables?

Comment: I have not tried yet. I will try with my ubuntu machine (I believe, it has latest perl) and let you know. Meanwhile, Can you please try in your machine too, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Regarding questions #2 and #3:

Your release mode output is the valid one:

- `use package1` finds, loads, compiles, and executes `package1.pm`. This defines `package1::sampleFunction`, which is exported into the `main` namespace. Exporting is effectively done by reference, and not by name, so `main::sampleFunction` points to the same function which `package1::sampleFunction` currently refers to.
- `require "package1.pm` does nothing because that package has already been executed.
- `require "package2.pm` finds, loads, compiles and executes `package2.pm`. This redefines `package1::sampleFunction`, which will warn if and only if you have `warnings` activated – either lexically through `use warnings` (do this) or globally with the `-w` switch (don't do this).
- `sampleFunction()` executes `main::SampleFunction`, which still points to the original subroutine.

  > from package1.pm
- `require "packagetest.pm"` finds, loads, compiles and executes `packagetest.pm`. Here in turn:

  - `use package1` will export `package1::sampleFunction` (which is currently the redefined subroutine) into the `packagetest` namespace.

  We also define the `packagetest::callSampleFunction` subroutine.
- We call `packagetest::callSampleFunction`, which in turn

  - calls `packagetest::sampleFunction`, which is the redefined subroutine

    > from package2.pm

#### A guess regarding #1:

The output could come together if we executed the script normally but kept the interpreter with its global state alive, then recompile and re-execute `sample.pl`. In this case, `package1.pm` and `package2.pm` would not be re-executed because they are already loaded. The `use package1` would then import the current `package1::sampleFunction` which already is the redefined version.

To test this hypothesis, restart your IDE and execute the script two times in debug mode. It should then output

```
from package1.pm
from package2.pm
```

during the first run, and

```
from package2.pm
from package2.pm
```

for all subsequent runs.

---

The real problem is

1. that you are redefining subroutines (don't do this),
2. that you are using the same package name `package1` in different files (don't do this),
3. that you are using a filename `package2.pm` that does not correspond to the package name `package1` inside (don't do this either), and
4. that you have a number of other style issues, including:

   - lowercase package names are reserved for “pragmatic modules”
   - don't export by default, instead use `@EXPORT_OK` and let the user of your module explicitly request some symbol
   - `require "filename"` is usually not something you want to do.
   - You did not `use strict; use warnings`
   - You are using warnings in production, but not in development? Why? :(
   - You are using the `-w` switch which is a bit oudated.

Comment: You mean, after 3rd step (`require "package2.pm"`), `main::sampleFunction` will refer to `package1::sampleFunction`, but at the same time `package1::sampleFunction` will be redefined to `package2::sampleFunction`. Am I right?

Comment: @InnovWelt yes, after `package1::sampleFunction` has been redefined, the names `package1::sampleFunction` and `main::sampleFunction` do not point to the same subroutine any longer.

Comment: @InnovWelt also, there is no `package2::` namespace.

Comment: @InnovWelt I updated with a hypothesis regarding #1, and included a way to verify this guess.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the irregularities. I have tried to reproduce a behavior from a pretty complex perl project which I am working on. This project has grown over time & it is having more irregulaties like this. I have to think of rewriting/correcting them :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48901/discussion-between-innovwelt-and-amon)

Comment: the debug mode prints
`from package2.pm
from package2.pm`
even during first run